# The input string is not in the correct format

Tags: wpf

```
private void btnComprobar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Inventario inv = new Inventario();

    inv.beneficio = txtBeneficio.Text;
    inv.idProducto = txtIdProducto.Text;
    inv.idProveedor = txtIdProveedor.Text;
    inv.precioEntrada = txtprecioEntrada.Text;

    //errores en la conversion de precioSalida y cantidad
    inv.precioSalida = double.Parse(txtPrecioSalida.Text);

    inv.cantidad = int.Parse(txtCantidad.Text);

    inv.clase = txtClase.Text;
    switch (txtClase.Text)
    {
        case "1":
            inv.clase = "FUTBOL";
            break;
        case "2":
            inv.clase = "RUNING";
            break;
        case "3":
            inv.clase = "BALONMANO";
            break;
        default:
            inv.clase = "1";

            break;

    }
    inv.descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text;
    inv.estado = txtEstado.Text;

    databaseConector.instance.comprobarProducto(dtGConsultas, inv);
}
```

error message:
The input string is not in the correct format.

In these two cases

```
Inv.precioSalida = double.Parse (txtPrecioSalida.Text);
```

Comment: Apparently the string in the txtPrecioSalida TextBox cannot be converted to a double. What is the value in the TextBox?

Comment: I have several text boxes, as filters the value is null at the time of the error

Comment: Are you saying that txtPrecioSalida.Text is null? You cannot pass null to the double.Parse method without getting an exception.

Comment: If that is, I tried it with tryParse but I am a newbie and I do not solve it

Answer (score -1):

The call to `double.Parse` will throw an exception if the `string` argument cannot be parsed to a `double` value. Same thing with `int.Parse`.

You could use the `double.TryParse`/`int.TryParse` method to *try* to parse the values:

```
private void btnComprobar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Inventario inv = new Inventario();

    inv.beneficio = txtBeneficio.Text;
    inv.idProducto = txtIdProducto.Text;
    inv.idProveedor = txtIdProveedor.Text;
    inv.precioEntrada = txtprecioEntrada.Text;

    //errores en la conversion de precioSalida y cantidad
    double precioSalida;
    if(double.TryParse(txtPrecioSalida.Text, out precioSalida))
        inv.precioSalida = precioSalida

    int cantidad;
    if(int.TryParse(txtCantidad.Text, out cantidad))
        inv.cantidad = cantidad;

    inv.clase = txtClase.Text;
    switch (txtClase.Text)
    {
        case "1":
            inv.clase = "FUTBOL";
            break;
        case "2":
            inv.clase = "RUNING";
            break;
        case "3":
            inv.clase = "BALONMANO";
            break;
        default:
            inv.clase = "1";

            break;

    }
    inv.descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text;
    inv.estado = txtEstado.Text;

    databaseConector.instance.comprobarProducto(dtGConsultas, inv);
}
```

Comment: If it has been very useful, I still need something because there are no errors but as part of a filter the search is done with null value and does not find any results, but many thanks.